# Django: How to insert data into field, where pk =?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-orm

Lets say I have an incident loaded into the database, where there is information in the `description` and `status` fields, but `action_taken` is left NULL.

```
class Incident(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, default="open")
    action_taken = models.TextField()
```

How can I load information into the `action_taken` field using this form and view?

**forms.py**

```
class ResolveForm(forms.Form):
    action_taken = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

**views.py**

```
def detail(request, incident_id):

    incident = get_object_or_404(Incident, pk=incident_id)
    template = "incidents/detail.html"

    if request.method == 'POST':    
        form = ResolveForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():     
            action_taken = (form.cleaned_data['action_taken'])

            ######### MY EFFORTS #########################
            q = Incident(action_taken=action_taken)
            q.save()
            print(incident.id)
            #new_incident, created = Incident.objects.get_or_create(action_taken)
            ##############################################

            return render(request, template, {'form': form})
    else:
        form = ResolveForm()        
        context = { 'incident': incident,
                    'form': form}

        return render(request, template, context)
```

**errors**

`incident.action_taken = action_taken`

error: name 'action_taken' is not defined

Comment: Why do you get `name 'action_taken' is not defined`? your `action_taken` comes from your line that reads `action_taken = (form.cleaned_data['action_taken'])`

Comment: Ah I believe I might have accidentally deleted it. Got it working! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I load information into the `action_taken` field using this form and view?

I see you already have your model instance `incident`, so this should do it

```
incident = get_object_or_404(Incident, pk=incident_id)
incident.action_taken = action_taken
incident.save()
```

If in your update you don't want to touch the other fields:

```
incident = get_object_or_404(Incident, pk=incident_id)
incident.action_taken = action_taken
incident.save(update_fields=['action_taken'])
```

To critique what you tried:

```
q = Incident(action_taken=action_taken)
q.save()
```

This doesn't get the object you want to update, but instead it creates a new one and saves it (not what you want)

Comment: Would it be `incident.action_taken = form.action_taken`?

Comment: Gotcha. I kept seeing examples for adding data, but not updating. Also I'm  getting the error `action_taken is not defined`.

Comment: Yeah my snippets are supposed to go in your `if form.is_valid()` block where `action_taken` is already defined by you